# Why is my react router not working on my server but does on my local env?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a route.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route exact path='/works/:worksId' component={Works} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Inside `<Home />` I have a nested component called `<Gallery />`. Inside gallery I have each image linked this way so the user would go to a detailed page.

```
<a href={`/works/${item.id}`}<img /></a>
```

When I test on my local env it works fine but after I upload the files to my server I get a "sorry this page does not exist 404 page". The urls are correct. I'm confused on why it works on my local but not after uploading.

Am I completely doing this the wrong way? How do I change pages from nested components?

Comment: You need server-side URL rewriting to support browser history mode in production. What HTTP server are you using to serve your app (eg nginx, Apache, etc)?

Comment: I'm using Apache